# show a button on the same page after submitting another button

Tags: laravel

I want a button to appear on `index.blade` after another button is clicked on the same page.the second button returns results in `index.blade` too and i want to show the new button after these results come back.
what's the easiest way to do it in Laravel.
sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: Use jquery/ajax for this .

Comment: isn't there a non ajax way at all?

Comment: yes there is another way. I'm assuming one button is form submission, once you submit a form return to the same page and pass the saved data with that response. then use isset to show the data.